# Can't visualize video duration

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I need to acquire the length of a video that I get with an input tag:

```
<input id="path" type="file" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" onchange="fileInput(this.files)" class="form-control-file">

<video id="preview" width="500" controls></video>
```

and here is my js:

```
function fileInput(files){
  document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
  var durata = document.getElementById("preview").duration;
  console.log(durata);
}
```

The  console log return a NaN
possibly I need to get as return time in this format HH:MM:SS

Comment: Do you need the `<video>` element before uploading the video? If it's not, you can create the video element inside the `fileInput` function, and estabilish a video trigger to get the length of the video, which will be in seconds (so you can convert it to the desired format).

Comment: ok thanks now i try your solution